# VB.net collection

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, collections

```
Class MainWindow

    Dim states As Collection = New Collection()

    Sub Output(Value As String)

        txtOutput.Text += Value + vbCrLf

    End Sub

    Sub ClearOutput(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        txtOutput.Text = ""
        txtInput.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

        Dim input As String = txtInput.Text
        'Dim state As String = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(",")).ToString
        'Dim stateID As String = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(" ")).ToString

        states.Add(input)
        Output("You added: " + input)

    End Sub

    Sub btnGet_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnGet.Click

        Dim stateID As String = txtInput.Text.ToString
        If states.Contains(stateID) Then
            Output("You requested: " + states.Item(stateID))
        Else
            Output("Not found")
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click

        Dim stateID As String = txtInput.Text.ToString
        If states.Contains(stateID) Then
            states.Remove(stateID)
            txtOutput.Text = ""
            Output(stateID + " removed; here's what's left:")
            OutputStates()
        Else
            Output("Not found")
        End If

    End Sub

    Sub btnShow_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click
        OutputStates()
    End Sub

    Sub OutputStates()
        For Each state As String In states
            Output(state)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm done with the Add and Show button.
the input is: California, CA

But my problem is the remove and get button. 
For example i inputted "CA" as a stateID, if i click the get or remove button, it will check if states collection has an item with the "CA" string, but the answer is always not found even if i use states(1).Contains(stateID) which is California, CA

Comment: There are a lot of better collection types in VB.NET. Please discard these leftover of VB6 heritage (if you can)

Comment: that was the code given by our prof, and we just need to add inputs instead of hard coded inputs.

Comment: Your prof surely wants you to exercise the For Each statement.  Iterating the collection and checking each element is required to find a match with "CA".

Comment: VB.NET is not a VB7. It is a completely new language with completely new libraries. Your prof should revamp his old assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET you would be using a `HashSet(Of T)`.

```
Dim states As HashSet(Of String) = New HashSet(Of String)()

states.Add(stateID)

If states.Contains(stateID) Then ...
```

Note that the HashSet is case sensitive by default. If you want it to be case-insensitive, initialize it like this:

```
Dim states As HashSet(Of String) = New HashSet(Of String)(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

---

Note also that (with `Collection`) `states(1)` returns a `stateID`. Therefore you could compare

```
states(1) = stateID 'Should return True if 1st state is "CA" and stateID is "CA"
```

`states(1).Contains(stateID)` makes no sense. Probably here `Contains` refers to the characters contained in `state(1)`.